# Добавить параметр ко всем запросам JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть сайт на `React` (но не SPA) со множеством ajax запросов через `JQuery`. Нужно ко всем GET/POST запросам добавить дополнительный параметр в URL.

Например, при `abc=123` запросы получатся следующие:

```
localhost:8080 -> localhost:8080?abc=123
localhost:8080?qwe=456 -> localhost:8080?qwe=456&abc=123
```

Как это сделать без переписывания всех запросов?

P.S. это мне нужно, чтобы номер сессии прописать в URL, так как Cookie для меня не подходит.

Comment: переопределите аякс метод в jquery и добавляйте в конец урла все что угодно, а потом вызывайте стандартный

Comment: вместо рефакторинга (дада, верю, что там 100к аякс запросов и это не рефакторится) переопределять ... Остер бы одобрил ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    var hasQM = options.url.indexOf("?") >= 0; // QM - question mark
    options.url = options.url + (hasQM? "&" : "?") + "abc=123";
});
```

Comment: для `post` бы еще

Comment: хотя ид сессии все равно через урл наверное передавать, хоть сам запрос и пост

Answer (score 3):

Приходит на ум что-то типа:
1) По всему проекту заменить `$.ajax` на скажем `ajaxRequest`
2) Сделать собственно обертку ...

```
function ajaxRequest( params ) {
  params.url += `${(/\?/.test(params.url) ? '&' : '?')}abc=123`;

  $.ajax(params);
}
```

Дальше уже от фантазии и разнообразия зависит, возможно придется менять не `url`, а `data` или ещё что-то ...

Comment: Переписывать запросы не имею возможности. Это закрытые компоненты.